# querySelectorAll for IE8 tips

Tags: internet-explorer-8, getelementsbyclassname, selectors-api

I have tried to understand how querySelectorAll works, because I have some problem to get this code to work in IE8.

Any ideas how i can solve it?
Regards

```
function leaving_site() {
    return confirm("Do you really want to leave site?");
}

function changeValue() {                                                                    // Larger Image 
    window.open(this.src.replace(/\.jpg/, "big.jpg"));
}



function init(){


    var external = document.getElementsByClassName("external");                             // Leaving site
    for (var i = 0; i < external.length; i++) {
            external[i].onclick = leaving_site;
            }

    var bild = document.getElementsByClassName("picture");                                      // Larger Image             
    for (var i = 0; i < picture.length; i++) {
            picture[i].onclick = changeValue;
            }

}

window.onload = init;
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact you gave yourself your answer. Just use `querySelectorAll` (supported in IE8). You have to use a class selector though.

```
function init() {
    // Leaving site
    var external = document.querySelectorAll(".external");
    for (var i = 0; i < external.length; i++) {
        external[i].onclick = leaving_site;
    }
    // Larger Image             
    var picture = document.querySelectorAll(".picture");
    for (var i = 0; i < picture.length; i++) {
        picture[i].onclick = changeValue;
    }
}
```

And there is a typo: `var bild` should be `var picture`, or vice versa